# Taking full screen images with Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, win32com, win32gui

I've tried a number of things, but all I can get if I try to do an auto screen shot of a full size window is a black screen.

I've tried ImageGrab.grab(), and automated Prt Scr press and I've had no luck.

The automated Prt Scr key press allowed me to manually paste the image correctly into paint, but if I tried to load it into Python using ImageGrab.grabclipboard() it came out black again.

hwnd=win32gui.GetActiveWindow() also gave me black images, although I wasn't sure if something else in win32gui would give me the correct results (it doesn't seem well documented).

The final thing I tried was an automated key press and win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_BITMAP) this gave me an integer result, which may or may not be black. If someone knows how to convert GetClipboardData to an image in Python, that would be great.

Or I'd appreciate any alternative suggestions. All of these methods (apart from the getClipboardData which I couldn't work out) worked for screenshots of windowed programs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

if isinstance(im, Image.Image):
... got an image ...
elif im:
   for filename in im:
       try:
           im = Image.open(filename)
       except IOError:
           pass # ignore this file
       else:
           ... got an image ...
else:
    ... clipboard empty ...
```

from http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm ?
If yes, post your adaptated code, full, so we can check it out.

Comment: I have tried that in the exact same format, from none full screen windows it is correct, but from full screen windows it just returns a totally black image. Thanks though. I may just make sure all the programs I need to screen shot are windowed.

Comment: @DNN, fullscreen windows graphic rendering are  handled completely different, and it would surely be tricky to screenshot them.